# Как запустить bash-скрипт в продуктдах JetBrains перед запуском?

Tags: bash, golang, jetbrains, environment-variables

Часто бывает нужно провести инициализацию перед запуском приложения. Например, эта операция может быть считыванием переменных окружения. Обычно это делается какой-нибудь утилитой. Например, bash-скриптом. Я обнаружил следующую возможность запустить скрипт:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я кладу в проект bash-скрипт. И добавляю его сюда:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но после запуска я получаю ошибку:

```
3:01 PM Error running 'export envs': Cannot run program "/home/user/go/src/***/ap/api/scripts/export_envs.sh" (in directory "/home/user/go/src/***/ap/api"): error=13, Permission denied
```

Пробовал давать права. Но это не помогает:

```
chmod 777 export_envs.sh
```

В чём причина?

Comment: ¿Зачем городить какой-то скрипт для установки переменных окружения, когда их можно задать прямо в настройках (Environment)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причина в том, что idea не умеет запускать баш скрипты как программы. И это не удивительно. Bash скрипты должен запускать bash. Скорее всего в качестве программы для запуска нужно указать `/bin/bash`, а как аргументы - `-c /*****/export_envs.sh`.

Comment: На самом деле, может. Как выяснилось, перезагрузка помогла. Не знаю, почему. Ваш вариант тоже сработал. Подскажите, каким образом в скрипте можно импортировать переменные так, чтобы они были бы доступны родительскому процессу? Есть ли варианты сделать это внутри скрипта? `source` не понимаю, как встроить

Comment: `export MYVAR="bu bu bu"`

Comment: Так будет работать только в рамках скрипта. Как только скрипт завершится, в родительском процессе этой переменной не будет

Comment: в целом, у дочернего процесса мало шансов повлиять на родительский. Но в Вашем случае это и не нужно. Вам нужно ведь передать эти параметры запускаемому процессу.

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы переменные окружения, которые лежат в файлике, в проекте, подцеплялись

Comment: там прямо на скриншоте видно. что можно подцеплять envfile. Пробовали?

Comment: Это плагин. К сожалению, он не работает на clearlinux. У одного из разрабов с ним проблемы